# Implementing a neural network classifier for my data, but is it solveable this way?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification

I will try to explain what the problem is.

I have 5 materials, each composed of 3 different minerals of a set of 10 different minerals. For each material I have measured the inensity vs wavelength. And each Intensity vs wavelength vector can be mapped into a binary vector of ones and zeros corresponding to the minerals the material is composed of.

So material 1 has an intensity of [0.51 0.53 0.57 0.68...... ] measured at different wavelengths [470 480 490 500 510 ......] and a binary vector 
[1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0]

and so on for each material.

For each material I have 5000 examples, so 25000 examples for all. Each example will have a 'similar' intensity vs wavelength behaviour but will give the 'same' binary vector.

I want to design a NN classifier so that if I give it as an input the intensity vs wavelength, it gives me the corresponding binary vector.

The intensity vs wavelength has a length of 450 so I will have 450 units in the input layer

the binary vector has a length of 10, so 10 output neurons

the hidden layer/s will have as a beginning 200 neurons.

Can I simly design a NN classifier this way, and would it solve the problem, or I need something else?

Comment: Can you explain how you create the binary vector in little more detail?

Comment: It is made by a genetic algorithm. The intensity vs wavelength is extracted from the pixels of a image and based on some fitness function and nonlinear combination, the GA decides this intensity vs wavelength belongs to this materials, so this specific binary vector. I don't know more about the GA though.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a pure machine learning question. With additional research, it may become a good fit for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) or [Data Science SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com).

Comment: why voting  to close off the topic? you could just message me and ask me politely to delete the topic if its inappropriate!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, however, be aware to use the right cost and output layer activation functions. In your case, you should use sigmoid units for your outer layer and binary-cross-entropy as a cost function.

Another way to go about this would be to use one-hot encoding so that you can use normal multi-class classification (will probably not make sense since your output is probably sparse).

Comment: I've looked for binary_cross_entropy on tensorflow but couldn't find it. There is however softmax cross entropy and sigmoid cross entropy? And which activation function do you recommend for the hidden layer? I am considering also sigmoid, but have read that relu or tanh might be also good

Comment: Use sigmoid_crossentropy_with_logits. For the hidden layer you can use whatever you wan't, you may wanna do some kind of hyperparameter tuning there. 
Today mostly ReLu and some variants of it are used since it is faster and counters the vanishing gradient problem, if I were you, I'd start with ReLu and test some others against it.